# Mozilla WebApp Manifest asks for HTTP Header

Tags: manifest, web-applications

I've been searching for hours, but cannot find a solution.
Currently I would like to upload a first webapp to Mozillas new platform, and the second step to do so is, to add a manifest file.
I took the information from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/apps/Manifest#path-handling) and try to build the manifest with the name manifest.webapp
But the result is the following message:

```
•Your manifest must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json". We saw "application/json".
```

What am I doing wrong. What line of code am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to add a line in your `.htaccess` file so Apache creates the HTTP headers. You can read for more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk%3aen/Apps/Manifest).