# Manifest app validation for Firefox Marketplace using GAE for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firefox, web-applications, manifest

I want to upload my app to the Firefox Marketplace.
When I try to validate my app manifest (called manifest.webapp), I got the following message:

> JSON Parse Error
>   Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Apps/Manifest#Serving_manifests for more information.

My app runs over Google App Engine for Java, so this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932010/mozilla-webapp-manifest-asks-for-http-header) doesn't work for me.
I tried adding the following lines to my web.xml file:

```
   <mime-mapping>
         <extension>webapp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-web-app-manifest+json</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

and didn't work either. 
Not sure if it would be possible to add something similar to the appengine-web.xml

Anyway, do you know how could I set it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an [issue with `<mime-mapping>`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5934) - try `<mime_mapping>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: no compilation issues making the change you said but still getting the same error message. Would it be possible to put the mime mapping somehow into the appengine-web.xml instead of the web.xml? Or if you see other possibilities... I'm really confused.