# mozilla market place submission error?

Tags: jquery, html, web, mozilla

I am submitting my [new app](http://www.onlinereversi.com) to mozilla market place. I am getting validation error.
validation throwing content type error.

```
Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Apps/Manifest#Serving_manifests for more information.
```

I am following all the guidelines but still getting error.

I added the below line to my .htaccess file in root directory.

```
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json .webapp
```

and my manifest URL is

[http://www.onlinereversi.con/manifest.webapp](http://www.onlinereversi.com/manifest.webapp)

how to resolve validation error?
Is there anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mozilla WebApp Manifest asks for HTTP Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932010/mozilla-webapp-manifest-asks-for-http-header)